# Accept just numbers on a TextBox ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, textbox, numbers

I have a `TextBox` & I want to accept just `numbers` in this TextBox when typing.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use the following client side code to do this:

```
jQuery.fn.ForceNumericOnly =
function()
{
    return this.each(function()
    {
        $(this).keydown(function(e)
        {
            var key = e.charCode || e.keyCode || 0;
            // allow backspace, tab, delete, arrows, numbers and keypad numbers ONLY
            return (
                key == 8 || 
                key == 9 ||
                key == 46 ||
                (key >= 37 && key <= 40) ||
                (key >= 48 && key <= 57) ||
                (key >= 96 && key <= 105));
        })
    })
};
```

Then in my aspx page I attach it to my TextBox with:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $("#<%= txtMyTextBox.ClientID %>").ForceNumericOnly();
});
```

This is a client side ONLY check so make sure to implement a server side check using like `Int32.TryParse` on your data as well to ensure that there is a number.

Comment: @Kesley : how can I implement that ?

Comment: @AZIRAR assuming you are using jQuery, you can just add the above javascript code, using `<script>` tags, to your aspx page  that you want to implement this on.  Then replace the `txtMyTextBox` with the name of your server side textbox control.

Answer (score 1):

A great way to accomplish this is to use the [MaskedEditExtender](http://www.asp.net/ajax/ajaxcontroltoolkit/Samples/MaskedEdit/MaskedEdit.aspx) in the Ajax control toolkit.

The example page even has a demo for limiting user input to just numbers and number-related characters.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the [AjaxControlToolkit](http://ajaxcontroltoolkit.codeplex.com/) then consider the FilteredTextBox extender.

```
<ajaxToolkit:FilteredTextBoxExtender ID="ftbe" runat="server" TargetControlID="YourTextBoxID" FilterType="Numbers" FilterMode="ValidChars" />
```